# Grep output of one and search in another grep

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I want to get the output of some failing messages, and use the output to search in same file ( from beginning)

I am able to get the first output, but how can I use that output to search in file matching string "his was the message we received"

```
grep -A1 "this is the subset which failed" "mylogs.log" | cut -d\( -f2 | tr -d $'\n' | tr -d $' '

Output : {failingbyte=0x8739872349723}
```

Then I want to grep this :

```
grep "This was the message we received" + above result in mylogs.log
```

Comment: How do i use the first command output as argument for second?

Comment: Now I got it. My mistake.

Comment: You're almost certainly going about this wrong and could get everything you need from mylogs.log with a single call to awk. [edit] your question to show sample input and expected output and tag your question with `awk` if you'd like help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can use a variable to hold the value like this:

```
failed=$(grep -A1 "this is the subset which failed" "mylogs.log" | cut -d\( -f2 | tr -d $'\n' | tr -d $' ')

grep "This was the message we received: $failed"
```

Or in one *ugly* line:

```
grep "This was the message we received: $(grep -A1 "this is the subset which failed" "mylogs.log" | cut -d\( -f2 | tr -d $'\n' | tr -d $' ')"
```

Comment: I think this is shell/environment specific. You should clarify which one you are using and maybe find out which one OP is using.

Comment: @Yannosch both this script and the OPs script contain bash-specific constructs (e.g. `$'\t'`) so I think it's safe to assume both are using bash.